# How to enter a value several times on ASP.NET Webpage?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-4.0

I have a webpage with a textbox and a button and when the button is clicked i get som calculations on the value entered, but i cannot enter another value and see calulations on that new number.

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I havent tried anything, i have just set up a textbox and a button, and when clicked some values are printed for example, value * 2 etc. But i want to enter another value to get that value * 2 and so on.

Comment: @HerrNilsson If your button already calculates the first time what doesn't work when you change the value and click it again? Give us the code sample. If you want help you'll have to include more, like code samples of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it sounds like you want to be able to change the values without having to click the button again, and have the calculations redone. The reason clicking your button works is because the page goes through a [Postback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback) The calculations are then processed server side and returned after the page has loaded. What you want to do can be accomplished in a handful of ways including: jQuery or ajax. One thing you may want to look at is [jQuery .post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) This can help you post the values of your form to a processing page and then set the return value on your form. On the other hand since you're using .NET you could also take a look at the [Microsoft AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) One place you could start is by looking at the [Update Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb399001.aspx). Good luck and I hope this helps!

Comment: I got it now, i had written my String.Format wrong.. Thanks for the help, i understand that the question was impossible to understand now ;)